# Osascript Compile Application

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line

Is there a way to compile an an applescript from the command line similar to the following.
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to this is surprisingly simple:

```
$ osacompile -o output.app input.applescript
```

This works for both plaintext `.applescript` files and the `.scpt` files that Script Editor makes.

You can use a pipe too, e.g. if you have the script on your clipboard:

```
$ pbpaste | osacompile -o output.app
```

Or `-e`, like the `osascript` command can use:

```
$ osacompile -o output.app -e "$(pbpaste)"
```

You can also use JavaScript with the `-l` flag:

```
$ osacompile -o output.app -l JavaScript -e 'app = Application.currentApplication();' -e 'app.includeStandardAdditions = true;' -e 'app.displayDialog("hi");'
```

Comment: The command in 0942v8653's answer will place the app in your current working directory—which, by default, is your home folder. If you need to specify the location in which the app will be saved, do something like this:
``` osacompile -o /Users/yourUsername/Desktop/aFolder/test.app -e "say \"Hello, there\""
```

Comment: To create only the compiled script, one can use `osacompile -x -o output.scpt input.applescript`. Then execute the compiled script (really fast) via `osascript output.scpt`.